# Why the type cannot be inferred if a parameterless method group is passed to LINQ methods?

Tags: c#, linq

Can someone explain me(or show the specification/documentation) why following is not allowed:

```
string[] fiveFoos = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(GetFoo).ToArray();
```

...

```
static string GetFoo()
{
    return "Foo";
}
```

Only this will compile:

```
string[] fiveFoos = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(i => GetFoo()).ToArray();
```

The integer projected from `Enumerable.Range` is not relevant and the method `GetFoo` is parameterless and clearly returns `String`, so why do i get following compiler error anyway:

> Error CS0411  The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.Select(IEnumerable, Func)' cannot be
>   inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.

Comment: I think I'd rather get the error when the method signature doesn't exactly match what's expected rather than potentially let a bug slip through. Like you said, making it a lambda is an easy way to overcome it.

Comment: **You** know that the integer values of `Enumerable.Range()` are irrelevant; because you're only interested in how many of them there are. But the compiler can't make that decision for you. It sees an `IEnumerable<int>` and doesn't care **where** it comes from or what the importance of the data is.

Comment: What's the deal with all these close votes? This is clearly *not* a typo, and the problem can be very easily reproduced, so it makes no sense to try and close this question on that specific ground.

Comment: I thought it was simply because it's expecting `Func<int, T>` so you can say `.Select(GetFoo)` where `GetFoo` is defined as `Func<int, string> GetFoo = (x) => "Foo";` for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The integer projected from `Enumerable.Range` is not relevant and the method `GetFoo` is parameterless and clearly returns `String`

The difference is exactly that `GetFoo` method is parameterless, while `i => GetFoo()` lambda is not. Adding a lambda that ignores its parameters matches the signature of `GetFoo()` method to the signature of `Func<int,T>` method expected by `Enumerable.Select`.

Defining a simple method for making sequences from parameterless generators fixes this problem:

```
static class MyEnumerable {
    public static IEnumerable<T> Generate<T>(Func<T> f, int n) {
        while (n > 0) {
            n--;
            yield return f();
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can write

```
string[] fiveFoos = MyEnumerable.Generate(GetFoo, 15).ToArray();
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/ZVTD98)

Comment: Maybe more generic: `public static IEnumerable<Tout> Generate<Tin, Tout>(this IEnumerable<Tin> seq, Func<Tout> f)
        {
            yield return f();
        }` Then i can use `string[] fiveFoos = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Generate(GetFoo).ToArray();`

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'm not sure it's cleaner, though, because it becomes a `Select` that ignores values of its first parameter. The implementation would also need a loop around `yield return` to ensure that the entire sequence gets transformed.

Answer (score 7):

`Select` here expects a `Func<int, string>` - your `GetFoo` method needs to take an `int` for this to work.

Method group conversion works by inferring the overload of the method which takes the appropriate parameters - you don't have one here. `The integer projected from Enumerable.Range is not relevant` - it might not be relevant to you, in this use case, but it is to the compiler!!

Comment: Almost complete answer. `Select` in this case does not know the return type of function  - so it expects sort of `Func<int, *>`. I.e. error would disappear if `static bool GetFoo(int)` used (indeed one would get another error on assignment part)